# How to get the value by checking from different criteria?

Tags: python, pandas

I have ID's that are unique to only one Person. If I can see the IDs in a specific month that means that Person is still in the company.

I would like to know:

1. How can I find out if this ID still exists in the following months?
2. The next condition is that the ID must be a executive and in which level the executive is (1-5 is possible)
3. Did the executive level change? If yes in which month?.

I am only interested in the result month by month not dates or anything else.

| ID | Month | Executive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Jan | 1 |
| 2 | March | 1 |
| 3 | Jan | 3 |
| 3 | Feb | 4 |
| 3 | March | 4 |

With this code I only get the the last month but not the months that are between:

```
result_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], keep='last')
print(result_df)
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of the input (the data you have) & output (the results you want).

Comment: Are the months always in the correct order?  The values do not appear to follow a specific pattern (so more difficult to sort), with Jan and March both existing.  And agreeing with @abdelgha4, how do you want the output to look, with the data you have provided?  Do you want to return a row for each month with one column with "still in company" and another with "changed executive level"?